# Two different names of same gothras

Tags: belief, culture, marriage

I somewhere heard that same gothras cannot get married. I have a friend who belongs to the gothras Srivatsa loved a boy of gothra Bhargavasa. Is there any possibility that both gothras are same but have different names?

Comment: `Is there any possibility that both gothras are same but have different names?` How to differentiate between them then?

Comment: @keth the major gotras are divided into subdivisions called ganas and each gana was further divided into groups of families. Today it is generally the gana or sub-gana that is commonly referred to as gotra so the confusion. However, since both Bhargava and Srivatsa arise from Bhrigu rishi in my opinion they belong to the same Gotra.

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be two different names of a same gotra. However, different gotras may have similar pravaras.

example : Vishvamitra and Kaushika gotras.

So pravara may not be confused with gotra. Pravara is name of some famous rishis of that gotra.

A rishi has an option of starting his own gotra with his name for his progeny.

Gotras like Jamadagni , Srivatsa, Vatula do share some of the same rishis in their pravara.

[Gotra pravara](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5tfeMr7jVAhUMNI8KHRbBB44QFghTMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxa.yimg.com%2Fkq%2Fgroups%2F23451465%2F193409882%2Fname%2FGothra-Pattika.&usg=AFQjCNHb5tNkIsgpJbPRaKna05MCzyf7Aw)

Answer (score 2):

Yes very much. Your friend and the boy both are Brahmins belonging to the BHARGAV lineage (descended from Bhrigu rishi). The Srivatsa, Vatsasya, Bhargava, Chyaavana, Aapnavaana, Aurva, Jaamadagney are all from the same family that originates from BHRIGU Rishi.

You can check out the following link for more on [Brahmin Gotra System](http://familypedia.wikia.com/wiki/Brahmin_gotra_system) or download the Gothra Patrika from [this](https://www.scribd.com/document/178776187/Gothra-Pattika) or [this link](https://www.scribd.com/document/242974594/Gothra-Pattika)

[image]

Comment: Link is not working. I think you have given link of your local system.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani check it now?

Comment: Yes, its correct now :-)

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal its not that these gotras are only for brahmins. Even kshatriyas and vyssyas have it.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi of course who denied that? This question is specifically for a Brahmin gotra though.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal where brahmin is mentioned in the question? even in brahmin too similar pravara may have multiple gotras.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I don't believe Srivatsa gotra appears in any Vaishya or Kshatriya lineages. If so please do share the link to such information.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal there is some confusion here. In your answer u have said that two gotras are same but in the table they list it separately. u can discuss this in chat room.